# Discord bot command list

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I have a list of commands for a discord bot, so I can change or modify them later. When someone writes a command in discord, I'm trying to check and see if its in the commands list. The problem is that I get the error:

```
    for message.content.startswith in commands:
AttributeError: 'str' object attribute 'startswith' is read-only
```

Is there a way to do this? How would I make it not read-only...or how would I fix this?

---

The code:

```
import discord, asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as: ', client.user.name, ' - ', client.user.id)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    commands = ('!test', '!test1', '!test2')

    for message.content.startswith in commands:
        print('true')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run('token')
```

Comment: You should look at the commands extension for `discord.py`.  The documentation for it is almost nonexistent, but there is an [example bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_bot.py)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This part is the issue:

```
for message.content.startswith in commands:
    print('true')
```

This doesn't make any sense. I assume `message.content` is a string. `startswith` is a string method, but it takes an argument, [see here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith). You need to pass `startswith` the actual characters you're searching for. For example, `"hello".startswith("he")` will return true. I believe this is what you want:

```
for command in commands:
    if message.content.startswith(command):
        print('true')
```